# Imgur blocking my IP? Works completely fine on my Amplify site, but when testing locally I get "Imgur is temporarily over capacity..." (React)

Tags: reactjs, api, imgur

I'd rather test it locally than have to publish to my site every time I need to test, but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
function GetAlbum(id){
    fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/album/" + id, {headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log("error", err))
}
```

Here is my function. I don't have a VPN to test if that works, but it doesn't work on Chrome/Edge/Firefox. There doesn't seem to be anything I can do.

Console log reads

```
data: Object { error: "Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later." }
​
status: 403
​
success: false
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to run the app at Network.

```
App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.x.xx:8080/ <- chose this one
```

You also need to pass the `response_type: 'token'`

Answer (score 1):

Found solution...

It doesn't work with: `localhost:3000`

Have to use your IPv4 address: `192.168.1.X:3000`